# log transform in linear regression

Tags: regression, data-transformation, linear, logarithm

Assume we have a data set and the theory suggests to model $Y \sim X$. We apply a simple linear regression and get the following:
[image]

Next, let us make a log transform of both $X$ and $Y$. The result is the following: [image]

The second picture "looks" much more linear than the first one.

The question: is it always better in this case to use log transform of the data? Also, I according to rolling cross-validation, the scores are very similar.

Comment: The top one looks fairly linear to me. There might be some issues with non-constant variance, but that’s nothing a weighted least squares can’t handle.

Comment: @Dave The problem with the top picture is its strong, clear heteroscedasticity, as you say.  One standard cure for this indeed is weighted least squares, but that would be inferior if the errors are multiplicative instead of additive (as WLS supposes). Ultimately the choice of procedures ought to depend on what we know or can deduce about the error structure--about which the OP is silent.

Comment: Dear Dave and @whuber, it is not much known abouth the error. The goal is to predict Y based on X. The model $\log Y \sim \log X$ is more linear and homoscedastic. Can then I conclude that  $\log Y \sim \log X$ is a better option for the forecast of $Y$?