# What are options if Rainbow test fails after Linear Regression

Tags: regression, nonlinear

I tested with commonly available [iris dataset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iris_flower_data_set) and ran [OLS](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.formula.api.ols.html) with following formula:

```
PW ~ SW + PL + SL + Species
```

Output is as follows:

```
                            OLS Regression Results                            
==============================================================================
Dep. Variable:                     PW   R-squared:                       0.954
Model:                            OLS   Adj. R-squared:                  0.952
Method:                 Least Squares   F-statistic:                     594.9
Date:                Sun, 12 Jul 2020   Prob (F-statistic):           3.03e-94
Time:                        21:56:13   Log-Likelihood:                 59.030
No. Observations:                 150   AIC:                            -106.1
Df Residuals:                     144   BIC:                            -88.00
Df Model:                           5                                         
Covariance Type:            nonrobust                                         
=========================================================================================
                            coef    std err          t      P>|t|      [0.025      0.975]
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Intercept                -0.4731      0.177     -2.679      0.008      -0.822      -0.124
Species[T.versicolor]     0.6481      0.123      5.263      0.000       0.405       0.892
Species[T.virginica]      1.0464      0.165      6.323      0.000       0.719       1.373
SW                        0.2422      0.048      5.072      0.000       0.148       0.337
PL                        0.2422      0.049      4.959      0.000       0.146       0.339
SL                       -0.0929      0.045     -2.084      0.039      -0.181      -0.005
==============================================================================
Omnibus:                        5.959   Durbin-Watson:                   1.844
Prob(Omnibus):                  0.051   Jarque-Bera (JB):                8.295
Skew:                          -0.168   Prob(JB):                       0.0158
Kurtosis:                       4.102   Cond. No.                         134.
==============================================================================

Warnings:
[1] Standard Errors assume that the covariance matrix of the errors is correctly specified.
```

Then I ran [Rainbow test](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.stats.diagnostic.linear_rainbow.html) and found that **P-value is 0.001**. Hence, linear regression is not appropriate here.

What are my options now? Thanks for your insight.

**Edit:**

The question being asked is what factors are independent determinants of PW (petal width) value?

The residual vs fitted plot is shown here:

[image]

The QQplot of residuals is shown below:

[image]

The distribution of residuals is as follows:

[image]

Comment: I suggest visualizing the residuals. That may give some insight into what kind of nonlinearity there is and how to model it. You also might determine that, while the test detects nonlinearity, that is only because there is a subtle (but real!) nonlinearity that isn’t enough to be interesting, and you may want to proceed with a linear model, anyway. An issue with checking assumptions via formal tests and p-values is that you miss the extent to which the assumption is violated. (This comes up frequently on here when people ask what to do when data is deemed non-normal via KS testing.)

Comment: This question cannot be answered without knowing *why* we are looking at this dataset in the first place. What question are you trying to use the data to answer? Depending on the answer to that, you might not even need to do anything.

Comment: I have added in question above: The question being asked is what factors are independent determinants of PW (petal width) value?

Comment: The distribution of residuals is reasonable so I can go ahead with linear model only. There seems to be some Heteroscedasticity and I read here https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/473603/log-transform-in-linear-regression that weighted least squares may be better for that.

Comment: it looks like you have some heteroscedasticity ('fan' pattern in residuals vs fitted plot); using the square root of petal width helps (but doesn't make the data pass the rainbow test).