# How to choose between different methods of linear regression?

Tags: regression, linear, robust

I find following commonly mentioned linear regression methods:

[OLS: ordinary least squares](https://www.statsmodels.org/devel/generated/statsmodels.formula.api.ols.html)

[GLS: generalized least squares](https://www.statsmodels.org/devel/generated/statsmodels.formula.api.gls.html)

[WLS: weighted least squaes](https://www.statsmodels.org/devel/generated/statsmodels.formula.api.wls.html)

[RLM: robust linear model](https://www.statsmodels.org/devel/generated/statsmodels.formula.api.rlm.html)

OLS is usually the default. I believe robust model is to be used to correctly handle outliers, but I am not clear about others.

What are the criteria to choose one over the other?

**Edit:** It is mentioned in the comments that it is a very broad question (I did not know that!). However, I would like to have a one or two lines on each of above to know the "indications" or when to use them.

OLS: default

RLM: if outliers are important and cannot be ignored.

That leaves only GLS and WLS. What would be most important reasons to use them?

Comment: This is very general, and whole books are needed for an answer. Could you limit the scope somewhat? Linear regression methods for ... ?

Comment: I have tried to specify that I need only a general indication on when to use each of these.

Comment: OLS is useful as *pedagogically* to generally introduce regression and it's concepts and assumptions, but I am not sure if or when I actually have used OLS in research. Regression methods permitting [creative violation of OLS regression's assumptions](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/100222/44269) permit us to model the complexities with which the world behaves with more fidelity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your links goes to statsmodels program web pages, a software I do not know. I will assume their use of terms is the standard.  A very general indication, just as a starter, what you really need is a book on regression.

- OLS is the starting point, many other models can be seen as extensions or generalization. Assumptions is continuous response, linear effects and constant variance + independence (of residuals.)
- GLS weakens assumption, do not assume constant variance nor independence. So you will need somehow to model the variance and covariances.
- WLS is GLS but with covariances zero, so really an assumption of independence of residuals.
- RLM is really a huge class of models and methods. Especially think about this for routine or automatized analyses.

Comment: I had asked earlier https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/146077/why-not-robust-regression-everytime . But I cannot understand how to adjust options in RLM since you say that RLM is "a huge class and methods".

Comment: It is suggested at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/473603/log-transform-in-linear-regression that WLS is useful if there is a problem of Heteroscedasticity.

Comment: Well, that is what I tried to say, *do not assume constant variance*.

Comment: as far as i know, the only difference between OLS and WLS is the weights that get multiplied as part of whitening, while no whitening is applicable for OLS. given this, i would like to know, how can assumptions become less stringent in WLS from OLS and how WLS can be useful when there is heteroscedasticity?